# The historical lock on the new post notices announcement should be removed and replaced with something else

Tags: discussion, meta, announcements, historical-lock

[New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide), the original announcement of the new post notices, has been historically locked. I understand the intention of doing so: the announcement has run its course, and new things should be posted as new questions rather than as answers to it.

However, the historical lock has an important and IMO undesired side effect: that specific lock reason also locks out the answers. Many of the answers there are still marked as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), and those issues can no longer be tracked. While moderators and SE staff with moderator rights can still edit and comment on them, users can no longer respond to comments or dismiss reasons on their answers. Also, this runs counter to the purpose of historical locks: these posts are [not meant to be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), they're meant to be retained in their original form as historical artifacts.

Additionally, there are [new questions about the post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341816/377214) popping up, that have already been asked as answers to the announcements, that are being voted as duplicates of the original announcement; while this would [ordinarily make sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330811/377214), this doesn't make sense if the issue it's being closed as a duplicate of is no longer trackable as an active issue.

I'd recommend removing the historical lock and either replacing it with a normal lock (which doesn't lock the answers), or just a normal closure (as is normally done with other announcements that have run their course but still have pending answers).

(Historically-locked questions also can't be flagged, and according to the FAQ on historical locks linked in the second paragraph, the proper way to draw attention to things about them is to make a meta post.)

Comment: [related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341619/freeform-lock-reasons-would-be-useful) - that's kinda my preferred solution to what I feel is the same issue. The question was inspired by the lock you mentioned and for the same reason

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Perhaps a "Wiki Answer" lock would make more sense? That prevents new answers, but allows editing / voting / commenting on existing ones. The downside is that the text is even more confusing than the historical lock.

Comment: The confusion is already an issue. I guess the other question is , what benefit do we have? Further input can be requested on meta, and the feature has been out a while

Answer (score 3):

Since I totally was the one who locked it, and left a comment as a signpost - in this case, saying that I intended to use the *functionality* of the historical lock, that it was fine to ask *new* questions, but that the current post would be left as is. I also encouraged folks to ask new questions *if* it was a new issue.

> I'd recommend removing the historical lock and either replacing it with a normal lock (which doesn't lock the answers

Locking answers is by design. Since the initial rollout of the feature seems to be done, it makes sense to raise new bugs and FRs as new questions. Anyone who needs to edit the issues can, and I'd assume the things under review should be tracked internally somewhere.

> Additionally, there are new questions about the post notices popping up, that have already been asked as answers to the announcements

By design

> that are being voted as duplicates of the original announcement

Not by design - though I guess if an answer is under review, eh - it would get fixed anyway. If its something new, it absolutely should not be closed as a dupe.

> I'd recommend removing the historical lock and either replacing it with a normal lock (which doesn't lock the answers)

Locking the answers is the point

> Just a normal closure (as is normally done with other announcements that have run their course but still have pending answers).

I guess but nothing really fit.

And that's kinda the thing here. Here's an exception. I used the tool *closest* to what I needed it, then posted a meta question asking for the tool *I actually needed*.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the part about users not being able to respond to comments or dismiss reasons on their answers.

Comment: If its dismissed, tis dismissed. If its important, and essential, we'll figure out something. The whole goal here is *that post has served its purpose*, and any further interaction should be elsewhere.

Comment: Comments on related issues are still being deleted

Comment: Comments are deleted. But on posts on this specific subject, eh, I'd leave it to a dev to request or do it themselves, assuming it isn't something completely unrelated. You *are* talking about Yaakov's post on the new post notices right?